# How to download from MediaFire?

Tags: android

I am developing an app and I have some .mp3 files in my drive. I have only free account, because files are only 2.5 GB. There is no direct download link, but in download button is link, but this link is generated at every reloading of web page. I cannot get this link by parsing with jsoup. Can you help me? Or some advice for drive. It cannot be Google drive, because it scan files and files greater than 90MB cannot be scanned and there is same problem. I want only 2.5gb.
Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most websites offering free services and direct links wipe their data regularly, so you can't have a permanent storage option. If you are fine with temporary data storage then check [this](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/file-to-link-offers-direct-download-without-wait-time-captcha-or-advertisements/).

Also, have you tried DropBox or OneDrive?

Comment: Thanks, I will try OneDrive, DropBox has only 2 GB of storage for free.